# Disc Format Settings for Video DVDs

Tags: video, dvd, format, dvd-burning, specifications

Does anyone know what disc settings are required for video DVDs?

There are plenty of programs that can simplify writing a video DVD (ie *Book B*, a disc playable on a traditional standalone DVD player) such as *DVD Flick* and *CloneDVD*, but what about other, multi-purpose disc-writing software like ImgBurn or CDBurnerXP? What disc format settings are required in those to write a video DVD?

In case of confusion, I am talking about the multitude of settings that can be set when writing an optical disc such as MODE1/MODE2, 2048/2352 byte sectors, file-system (*only* UDF? what version?), meta data/volume identifiers, character set, filename length settings, Unicode support, and so on.

For example, in ImgBurn, look at the Options, Labels, and Advanced tabs of the writing modes. There are a lot of options that can be configured, but I cannot find any information on what settings are used for a video DVD. The closest I can find is [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video), which merely briefly mentions file-systems and [a page](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/0,,sid9_gci514667,00.html) which has more information but not this specific topic. Most of the technical information that I can find is about the format of the (MPEG2) video itself as opposed to the technical specs of the disc. I also tried looking up the Book B standard (I *assume* it should be in there), but that seems to require a few-hundred-dollar subscription.

Answer (score 0):

From "*the official Internet* [DVD FAQ](http://dvddemystified.com/dvdfaq.html)":

> Almost all DVD-Video and DVD-ROM discs use the UDF bridge format, which is a combination of the DVD MicroUDF (subset of UDF 1.02) and ISO 9660 file systems.

Following links there to the [UDF 1.02 spec](http://www.osta.org/specs/pdf/udf102.pdf), the sector size is 2048, which I have seen mentioned elsewhere. Hopefully you can find any other relevant details, or figure them out with some test disks.

Comment: Hmm, section [5.2](http://dvddemystified.com/dvdfaq.html#5.2) of the DVD FAQ seems to conflict with section 6.9.1 of the [UDF spec](http://www.osta.org/specs/pdf/udf102.pdf). I looked through the contents (as well as used the heck out of the F3 key), but the DVD FAQ seems to only mention file-systems. And if I am interpreting the OSTA spec correctly, it seems to say that ***all*** DVD media uses 2048B sectors regardless of content. :-?